# i have problem connceting snowsql to snowflake its showing error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
C:\Users\raxz>snowsql -a dr61159.ap-southeast-1.aws -u raxz
Password:
250001 (n/a): Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!
```

can any one help me
thanks
raxz

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the account value being used. It should not have .aws. Here is the correct account value for your case:

```
C:\Users\raxz>snowsql -a dr61159.ap-southeast-1 -u raxz
```

The account identifiers details are mentioned here in the following documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#non-vps-account-locator-formats-by-cloud-platform-and-region

Comment: thanks srinath  , but i try to with out account value .aws bt still its throw error like this  
              C:\Users\raxz>snowsql -a dr61159.ap-southeast-1 -u raxz
Password:
250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: dr61159.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!

Comment: im  trying  this way  also      C:\Users\raxz>snowsql -a dr61159.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com -u raxz
Password:
250001 (n/a): Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!      help me with this problem

Comment: Use the following connection string and provide the debug log that is generated for this. snowsql -a dr61159.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com -u raxz -o log_level=debug -o log_file=<path>
In the meantime, for testing purpose can you change the default UI from Snowsight to Classic UI and share the results? I tested the URL https://dr61159.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com which redirects to Snowsight as part of default UI setting at the account level.

Comment: thanks srinath , im trying to solve all the ways but its showing same error , in that time im using classic ui   error is C:\Users\raxz>snowsql -a dr61159.ap-southeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com -u raxz -o log_level=debug
Password:
250001 (n/a): Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 0 attempt(s).Aborting
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!